# How can I add a jQuery .data() attribute to a dropdownlist option element

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add some extra data using jQuerys .data() to a element on a dropdownlist, the dropdown list is populating property and the ID I want is there, but when I try and access the data is showing up and undefined.

Population code.

```
 $.each(tutorArray, function(index, item){
        var TID= item.T.Id        
        $.each(item.T.TimeList, function(ind, i) {
            $(ddl).append($('<option></option>').val(i.StartTime).html(i.StartTime + ' - ' + i.EndTime).data({
                TID: TID
            }));
        });
    });
```

access code

```
$(ddl).bind('change', function() {
        if($(this).val() != '') {

            var time = $(this).val(); 

            showConfirmRequestTutorCallDialogue(d, time, $(ddlDurationSelector).val(), $(this).data("TID"), $(ddlStudiesSelector).val())
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks from my research that this is not possible the .data() needs to be on a element not on a sub part. So it cant be attached to a `<option>` element

What I did instead was to include the data within the value field then split it out when the value was accessed.

Set Code

```
       var element = $('<option></option>');
       element.val(i.StartTime +"--" +TID).html(i.StartTime + ' - ' + i.EndTime);
```

Access Code

```
        var str = $(this).val();
        var substr = str.split('--');
        var time = substr[0];
        var TID = substr[1];
```

Answer (score 5):

You should set `data` for the element this way ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)):

```
element.data("someKey", someValue);
```

So your population code could look like this:

```
$.each(tutorArray, function(index, item){
    var TID= item.T.Id        
    $.each(item.T.TimeList, function(ind, i) {
        var element = $('<option></option>');
        element.val(i.StartTime).html(i.StartTime + ' - ' + i.EndTime);
        element.data("TID", TID);
        $(ddl).append(element);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have changed the population code over but when I go to get the data back it is still showing up and undefined.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

I would try using camel case for your data attribute name, since the documentation shows that html 5 is doing some magic behind the scenes when processing the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

**A solution with a modified version of already said approach**

Thought its months after you asked the question, still I thought of including it so that it may help other users while they lookup for a similar problem.
I happen to bounce on a similar problem recently, and I saw this thread and used the answer by  Tadeck to set the data values for a dropdown using jquery.

At first the data values were not beeing set properly as you mentioned as well, but then I twigged the approach and did something (see below) which helped me set/retrieve the data values in jquery.

```
var element = $('<option></option>');  
element.val('id').text('uiName');  
$(element).data("type", 'mytype');
```

// Here only change is that, instead of doing a element.data(...) I called the element as a jquery dom element using the $ which somehow happen to set the values properly and i can now retrieve the data fields as well!

Hope this might help other users facing similar prolems

Answer (score 1):

No need to split your values, you can simply do.

```
var element = $(' <option data-type1="" data-type2=""></option>');
```

Just add as many fields using data-(any property)

set -  `$(element).data("type1", yourValues);`

get - `$("#dropdownID :selected").data("type1");`

Comment: var element = $('<option data-type1="" data-type2=""></option>');