# jQuery adding additional data to dynamically created select option

Tags: jquery

I am populating a select element dynamically through an ajax call that returns a JSON object with several attributes like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "get_data.php",
        data: {value:someValue},
        dataType: "json", 
        cache: false,
        success: function(dataSet){
            $("#mySelect").empty().append('<option value="">default option</option>');
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(dataSet)){
                $.each(dataSet, function(i, data){
                    var option = $("<option>");
                    option.val(data.id);
                    option.text(data.description);
                    option.data("test", 1);
                    $("#mySelect").append(option);
                });
            }

            $("#mySelect").removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("Populate mySelect Error: " + data.error);
        }
    });
```

The bit about option.data("test", 1) was me playing around with the idea of adding additionally returned attributes to my dynamically created option elements. This doesn't seem to be working. Any insight on how I can get my additional data attached to my option elements? I'm pretty new to jQuery and client side scripting, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What you have should work. Note though, that adding `data` in jQuery will not be visible in the HTML source, only by accessing the object through jQuery itself.

Comment: What you mean by not working?

Comment: it should work.. how are you saying it is not working

Comment: That was my problem Rory. I was checking the HTML source. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a jQuery .data() attribute to a dropdownlist option element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392138/how-can-i-add-a-jquery-data-attribute-to-a-dropdownlist-option-element) - don't think it's possible with data but using rohan's answer below it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
option.attr("data-test", 1);
```

Comment: I dont see any problem in `option.data("test", 1)`